# Problem occurs while implementing Stripe Payment

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am studying how to build an e-commerce IOS app using Stripe payment gateway everything goes alright until I run this line of code :

```
paymentContext.requestPayment()
```

it gives me this error :

> Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

I have tried every possible solution but still get the same error.

1. I thought that it happened because there is no default src because when I add the card to the user it's not shown in the customers list in stripe dashboard just like this

[customer without payment method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtW8i.png)

but I solve it by doing this in **XCode**

```
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
            }
```

and this in my `index.js`

```
    exports.attatchPaymentMethod = functions.https.onCall(async (data , context) => {

    const paymentMethod = data.paymentMethod;
    const customer = data.customer;

    const updatedCustomer = await stripe.customers.update(
        customer,
        {invoice_settings: {default_payment_method: paymentMethod}}
      );

    return updatedCustomer

})
```

But when I add the card manually to the stripe website , no problem happens and I don't get this error.
I found that there is a difference between the card added by the app and the one added by the website.

this is the card added by the app:

[card added by the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXDbc.png)

and this is the card added by the website:

[card added by the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3pAk.png)

I spent a lot  and a lot of hours trying to solve but I couldn't

and here. is my full **checkoutVC code**

```
    class CheckoutViewController: UIViewController, CartItemDelegate {
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var selectPaymentMethodBtn: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var serviceFeeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var delivaryFeeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var subtotalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    var paymentContext : STPPaymentContext!
    
    
    var sourceParams : STPSourceParams!
    var cardParams : STPCardParams!
    var paymentResult : STPPaymentResult!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setupTableView()
        setupPaymentInfo()
        setupStripeConfig()
        
        
    }
    
    
    func setupTableView(){
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.cellIdentifiers.CartItemCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.cellIdentifiers.CartItemCell)

    }
    
    func setupPaymentInfo(){
        serviceFeeLabel.text = StripeCart.proccessingFees.penniesToFormattedCurrency()
        delivaryFeeLabel.text = StripeCart.shippingFees.penniesToFormattedCurrency()
        subtotalLabel.text = StripeCart.subtotal.penniesToFormattedCurrency()
        totalLabel.text = StripeCart.total.penniesToFormattedCurrency()
    }
    
    
    func setupStripeConfig(){
        
        let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared
        config.requiredBillingAddressFields = .full
        
        
        let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: StripeApi)
        paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext, configuration: config, theme: .defaultTheme)
        
        paymentContext.paymentAmount = StripeCart.total
        
        paymentContext.delegate = self
        paymentContext.hostViewController = self
        
        
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func selectPaymentMethodClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        paymentContext.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()
    }

    
    
    func removeItem(product: Product) {
        StripeCart.removeItemFromCart(item: product)
        tableView.reloadData()
        setupPaymentInfo()
        paymentContext.paymentAmount = StripeCart.total
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func placeOrderClicked(_ sender: RoundedButton) {
        
        paymentContext.requestPayment()
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

and this is my `STPPaymentContextDelegate code`

```
    extension CheckoutViewController : STPPaymentContextDelegate {
    func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
        
        if let paymentMethod = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption {
            selectPaymentMethodBtn.setTitle(paymentMethod.label, for: .normal)
            
            
            
            paymentResult = STPPaymentResult.init(paymentOption: paymentMethod)
            
            
            var myPaymentMethod = (paymentResult.paymentMethod)
            
                     
            print("myPaymentMethod IS \(myPaymentMethod)")
            print("The paymentMethod is \(paymentMethod) and the user is \(UserService.user.stripID)")
            
          
            let data : [String : Any] = [
                "paymentMethod" : (paymentResult.paymentMethod?.stripeId)! ,
                "customer" : UserService.user.stripID
            ]
            
            
            Functions.functions().httpsCallable("setupIntent").call(data) { result, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
            }
            

            Functions.functions().httpsCallable("attatchPaymentMethod").call(data) { result, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
            }

          
        } else {
            selectPaymentMethodBtn.setTitle("Select Method", for: .normal)
        }
        

        
    }
    
    
    
    
    func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "ERROR", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action in
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        let retry = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default) { action in
            self.paymentContext.retryLoading()
        }
        
        
    }
    
    

    
    func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {
        
        let idempotency = UUID().uuidString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        
            
            let data : [String : Any] = [
            
                "total" : StripeCart.total ,
                "customerID" : UserService.user.stripID ,
                "idempotency" : idempotency
                
            ]
            Functions.functions().httpsCallable("makeCharge").call(data) { result, error in
                
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    completion(STPPaymentStatus.error , error)
                    return
                }
                StripeCart.clearCart()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.setupPaymentInfo()
                completion(STPPaymentStatus.success, nil)
            }
        
    }
   
    
    func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
        
        let title : String
        let msg : String
        switch status {
        case .success:
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            title = "SUCCESS"
            msg = "THX FOR YOUR SHOPPING"
        case .error:
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            title = "ERROR"
            msg = error?.localizedDescription ?? ""
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        case .userCancellation:
            return
        }
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        self.present(alert, animated: true , completion: nil)
        
    }
    
}
```

and this is my `index.js`

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { user } = require("firebase-functions/v1/auth");

admin.initializeApp()

const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_test_key)

var customer ;

exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.firestore.document('users/{id}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

    const data = snap.data();
    const email = data.email;

    customer = await stripe.customers.create({ email: email })

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(data.id).update({stripID : customer.id})

});

exports.attatchPaymentMethod = functions.https.onCall(async (data , context) => {

    const paymentMethod = data.paymentMethod;
    const customer = data.customer;

    const updatedCustomer = await stripe.customers.update(
        customer,
        {invoice_settings: {default_payment_method: paymentMethod}}
      );

    return updatedCustomer

})

exports.setupIntent = functions.https.onCall(async (data , context) => {

    const paymentMethod = data.paymentMethod;
    const customer = data.customer;
    const setupIntent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({customer: customer , payment_method: paymentMethod , payment_method_types: ['card'] , usage: 'off_session'});

    return setupIntent


})

exports.makeCharge = functions.https.onCall(async (data , context) => {

    const customerID = data.customerID;
    const total = data.total;
    const idempotency = data.idempotency;
    const uid = context.auth.uid;

    if (uid === null) {
        console.log('Illegal Access')
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied' , 'Illegal access attempt')
    }

    return stripe.charges.create({
        amount: total,
        currency: 'JOD',
        customer: customerID
    }, {
        idempotency_key: idempotency
    }).then( _ => {
        return
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal' , err)
    });

})


exports.createEphemeralKey = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    const customerID = data.customer_id;
    const stripeVersion = data.stripe_version;
    const uid = context.auth.uid;

    if (uid === null) {
        console.log('Illegal Access')
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied' , 'Illegal access attempt')
    }

    return stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
        {customer: customerID} , 
        {stripe_version: stripeVersion}
        ).then((key) => {
            return key
            print(key)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            print(err)
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal' , 'unable to create ephemeral key')
        })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

> this line of code :
> paymentContext.requestPayment()
> it gives me this error :
> Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Hmm, you would never get that error from calling requestPayment on STPPaymentContext directly. You would only get if you were calling the deprecated /v1/charges API on your backend server.

So the error is actually coming from your server, it's the response you get from `Functions.functions().httpsCallable("makeCharge")`

You didn't share that backend code, but you probably call the Stripe Charge API with just the customer ID, which would give you the error you mention, and won't work. Your workaround of manually adding the card to a customer object first is not really the best way to approach this.

The correct way to implement that is that you read the PaymentMethod object ID from the PaymentResult in the `didCreatePaymentResult` delegate function :

`paymentResult.paymentMethod`

https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPPaymentContextDelegate.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(pl)STPPaymentContextDelegate(im)paymentContext:didCreatePaymentResult:completion:

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#submit-payment

Right now you probably call the Stripe Charge API with just the customer ID, which would give you the error you mention, and won't work. You should be calling the backend server to get a PaymentIntent object, and then calling `STPPaymentHandler.shared().confirmPayment` to confirm that PaymentIntent with the PaymentMethod object from the delegate callback. There's example code for that in the Stripe docs link above.

Overall you're doing a few confusing things since you're using STPPaymentContext instead of the newer PaymentSheet which is the default integration. The guide for using Stripe with an iOS app is at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios and that's the right integration to use, right now you're using a legacy approach that has less documentation and has some confusing behaviour.